# Executing again after the task is done

Tags: java, printing

I want to pause for about 10 mins after the printing of 30 copies (literally printing in printer) is done and execute it again.

```
public class printImage {
    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(new Copies(30));

        PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);

        PrintService ps = pss[4];
        System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);

        DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("mypic.JPG");
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);

        job.print(doc, pras);
        fin.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: is this java? then please tag accordingly

Comment: sorry. just new here. edited by the way

Comment: add a loop and a Thread.sleep(600000) to your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to check [PrintJobListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/event/PrintJobListener.html) interface.

> Implementations of this listener interface should be attached to a
>   DocPrintJob to monitor the status of the printer job. These callback
>   methods may be invoked on the thread processing the print job, or a
>   service created notification thread. In either case the client should
>   not perform lengthy processing in these callbacks.

You can modify your code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PrintException {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(new Copies(30));

        PrintService pss[] = (PrintService[]) PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);

        PrintService ps = pss[4];
        System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);

        DocPrintJob job = pss[0].createPrintJob();

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("mypic.JPG");
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);

        // Monitor print job events
        PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

        job.print(doc, pras);

        // Wait for the print job to be done
        pjDone.waitForDone();

        fin.close();

    }
```

The class `PrintJobWatcher` is:

```
class PrintJobWatcher {
    // true iff it is safe to close the print job's input stream
    boolean done = false;

    PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
        // Add a listener to the print job
        job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
            public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }
            public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }
            public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }
            public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                allDone();
            }
            void allDone() {
                synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
                    done = true;
                    PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public synchronized void waitForDone() {
        try {
            while (!done) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

When your printing job is done you can put a sleep call there rather than `allDone` method.